# replacing a string and keeping numbers intact

Tags: php, html, regex

i got this table generated with php: 
a function generates a string with all the html code:

`<table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>4</td><td>6</td><td>8</td><td>10</td><td>12</td><td>14</td><td>16</td><td>18</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>6</td><td>9</td><td>12</td><td>15</td><td>18</td><td>21</td><td>24</td><td>27</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>8</td><td>12</td><td>16</td> .... </table>`

now i want to make the numbers 1 to 10 black. i'm trying to replace `'<td>(10|[0-9])</td>'` with `<td style="font-weight: bold">THE-ORIGINAL-NUMBER</td>`.

Thanx in advance!

p.s. i know there're alot of similir answers out there but i just couldnt figure it out.. is there an actually noob-friendly tut/glossary of regex out there? i couldn't really find a modern day site.

Comment: if you can guarantee that the html is going to look like how you say but you should really read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: It would be better CSS/HTML-wise to give all the relevant TD elements a class (e.g. `<td class="low_n">`) and then define the css class as being `font-weight: bold`. That way, if you decide to change the appearance of these table elements, or even decide you no longer want those figures highlighted, you can just change the css declaration; you don't have to edit the page source.

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ that thread hurt my brain.

Comment: @i_alarmed_alien i know, this was just an example for school. thnxs for pointing that out though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are matching this regular expression:

```
<td>(10|[0-9])</td>
```

You are capturing `10|[0-9]` into capture group #1. This can be referenced in your replacement with either of the following [***backreferences***](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html):

```
\1
$1
```

---

Full PHP code:

```
$html = '<td>1</td>';
$html = preg_replace(
  '~<td>(10|[0-9])</td>~',
  '<td style="font-weight: bold">\1</td>',
  $html
);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this regex

```
(?<=<td>)(10|[0-9])(?=<\/td>)
```

replace group #1 with:

```
<span class="BoldText">$1</span>
```

Style:

```
.BoldText {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `<b>` may be useful:

replace

```
'~<td>(10|[0-9])</td>~'
```

with

```
'<td><b>\1</b></td>'
```

Comment: don't have enough rep bro :/